# Cuál es la complejidad algorítmica de este programa?

Tags: python, algoritmos, complejidad

Hola tengo este programa  que calcula los numeros EMIRP y estoy aprendiendo a calcular la complejidad algoritmica pero ando un poco perdido , este es el código

```
import time
start = time.time()

def prime_number(num,c_p=0):
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        if num % i == 0:c_p += 1
        if c_p > 2: return 0
    return 1 if c_p == 2 else 0

def change(N):
    if(len(N) >= 2):
        return 1 if int(N[::-1]) != int(N) and prime_number(int(N[::-1])) == 1 else 0
    return 0

LP = [i for i in range(1,1001) if(prime_number(i)) == 1]
NLP = [print(i) for i in LP if(change(str(i))) == 1]
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Como se cual es la complejidad algoritmica ? No se si lo correcto es que sea O(N)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Teoría

La complejidad es una medida del número de operaciones que el código tiene que hacer para una entrada de datos de tamaño N.

Por ejemplo, para extraer el elemento 0 de una lista de N elementos, basta una sola operación:

```
dato = lista[0]
```

Esto no depende del tamaño de la lista, es decir, no depende de N, por lo que su complejidad se denota por O(1).

En cambio, si quieres encontrar el mayor elemento de una lista de positivos, con un algoritmo como este:

```
mayor = 0
for elemento in lista:
   if elemento > mayor:
      mayor = elemento
```

entonces, contemos instrucciones:

- Una para inicializar
- En cada iteración del bucle for se repetirán las siguientes instrucciones:

  - Extraer el siguiente elemento de la lista (digamos que esto se hace en un solo paso, es decir, que acceder al siguiente elemento de la lista tiene complejidad O(1), lo mismo que acceder a un elemento cualquiera de ella)
  - Asignarlo a la variable `elemento`
  - Comparar con `mayor`
  - Quizás asignar (o no, según la comparación anterior) el resultado a `mayor`

Como vemos, cada iteración del for daría lugar a 3 ó 4 instrucciones. Pongámonos en el peor caso y digamos 4 (esto ocurriría si todos los elementos de la lista estuvieran ordenados de menor a mayor).

Si la lista tiene N elementos el número de operaciones del algoritmo anterior sería entonces 1 + 4N.

Cuando se usa la notación O(), de la fórmula anterior se queda uno con sólo un término, que sea el que más rápido crece (por ejemplo, el que tenga N elevado a la mayor potencia). Sería 4N en nuestro ejemplo. Y se descartan también los coeficientes (el 4). Por tanto ese algoritmo sería O(N).

Como ves, con tal de que tenga un bucle sobre la lista, la complejidad es O(N) sin que importen las instrucciones que hay en el bucle, con tal de que todas esas instrucciones no dependan de N.

Imagina ahora que queremos sumar a cada elemento de la lista el valor del máximo. Según cómo lo resolvamos la complejidad puede variar. Por ejemplo así:

```
def mayor(lista):
   mayor = 0
   for elemento in lista:
       if elemento > mayor:
          mayor = elemento

max = mayor(lista)
for i in range(len(lista)):
   lista[i] += max
```

En este caso tendríamos:

- La definición de la función `mayor()`. Definir funciones tiene complejidad O(1), puesto que depende del número de líneas de la función, no del tamaño de la lista, y aquí estamos considerando como entrada la lista.
- Llamada a la función `mayor()`. Esto tiene complejidad O(N) como vimos antes.
- Otro bucle que itera por la lista para sumarle el mayor. Este bucle tendría también complejidad O(N) puesto que el número de operaciones total depende de la longitud de la lista.

El total sería por tanto O(1) + O(N) + O(N), lo que vendría a ser O(1+N+N), es decir O(1+2N), es decir O(N) otra vez. Mientras los diferentes bucles que haya en el programa estén uno tras otro y no anidados, la complejidad sigue siendo O(N) porque los coeficientes delante de la N no se tienen en cuenta, y por tanto nos da igual que haya uno, dos o cien bucles. Cada uno es O(N) y todos juntos también O(N).

Ahora bien, si lo hubiésemos programado de esta otra forma:

```
def mayor(lista):
   mayor = 0
   for elemento in lista:
       if elemento > mayor:
          mayor = elemento

for i in range(len(lista)):
   lista[i] += mayor(lista)
```

la cosa cambia completamente. La definición inicial es la misma, O(1), pero ahora el bucle, aunque se repite N veces, en cada repetición llama a `mayor()` que tiene complejidad O(N). Por tanto estamos haciendo N veces una O(N) lo que nos da una O(N²)

Es decir, si tenemos un bucle anidado la complejidad cambia.

## Tu caso

Ahora tienes las bases para analizar tu código. De mano veo que `LP` se crea mediante una *list comprehension*, que es una forma más compacta de bucle, y por tanto tiene complejidad O(N), pero hay que mirar qué se hace en cada iteración del bucle, y vemos que en cada iteración se llama a `prime_number()`.

Si miras esta función ves que contiene otro `for` que va de 0 al número considerado, por tanto cuanto mayor sea la lista inicial, más veces irá iterando también este otro bucle, que es por tanto otro O(N) (anidado en el anterior). Dentro de este bucle el tipo de operaciones que hay son simples comparaciones y asignaciones, que son O(1).

Por tanto la asignación a `LP` tiene complejidad O(N²).

Después viene otra asignación `NLP` que lleva otro bucle `for` encubierto que aunque no se repite N veces, si se repite un número variable de veces que depende de N. Es difícil no obstante saber con qué fórmula depende de N pues depende del número de primos que haya entre 0 y N, pero en general sabemos que crece a un ritmo menor que N, así que este bucle a priori parece que tendría menos peso en la complejidad que el bucle anterior. Pero eso depende también de qué haga dentro del bucle, y vemos que llama a `change()` así que habrá que analizar esta función.

Esta función recibe un parámetro y hace algunas operaciones con él. Mira su longitud (esto tarda O(1) o O(N) dependiendo de como python implemente el operador `len()`, es decir, si la longitud de la cadena ya está almacenada como parte de la misma y sólo hay que leerla, o si hay que buscar dónde termina la cadena para lo cual habrá que recorrerla hasta el final). Después da la vuelta a la cadena con la expresión `[::-1]`, lo cual requiere recorrer esa cadena y por tanto O(N), la convierte en `int()`, lo que en general también será O(N) porque hay que mirar sus dígitos. Y verifica también si el entero resultado es primo, llamando a `prime_number()`, la cual como vimos tiene también complejidad O(N).

Por tanto `change()` contiene varias operaciones O(N), pero ya que no se hacen de forma anidada, sino secuencial (primero se da la vuelta a la cadena, luego se aplica `int()` luego se aplica `prime_number()`), la función completa tiene complejidad O(N), siendo en este caso N el parámetro de entrada de la función, no el tamaño de la lista de entrada, o sea del `range(1,1001)`.

Pero ya que ese parámetro era un elemento de `LP` y el tamaño de esos elementos dependía también del tamaño del problema, podemos decir que la función `change()` tiene complejidad O(N) siendo N también el tamaño del problema.

Así que la asignación de `NLP` es un bucle de que se repite O(algo que crece más despacio que N) veces, y cada vez tiene complejidad O(N). El bucle completo será O(algo que crece más despacio de N²), así que menor que la del primer bucle y por tanto no "cuenta" en el total.

> La complejidad total es finalmente O(N²).
>
> **EDICION**. No estoy tan seguro de lo anterior. Me he dado cuenta de que el bucle interno de `prime_number()` no se ejecuta realmente `N` veces, pues se sale del bucle tan pronto como detecta que el número no es primo. Sólo se ejecutará N veces si es primo, pero esto será poco frecuente. Es decir, creo que la complejidad estaría entre O(N) y O(N²), pero la fórmula exacta depende de la densidad de distribución de primos dentro de los enteros.

## Experimenta

Además, puedes verificar eso experimentalmente ya que estás tomando tiempos de ejecución. Prueba a ir variando el valor del `range(1,1001)` y tomando tiempos según el `range()` crece. Deberías ver que el tiempo crece proporcionalmente al *cuadrado* del tamaño de ese `range()`.

A mi me sale así:

[image: Grafica]

lo que se ajusta bastante a una O(N²). En todo caso crece mucho más deprisa que una O(N):

[image: comparación]

Comment: La notación `O(g(x))` (*O grande*) se supone que es una **cota superior**, para nada indicativo de lo optimizado que sea el algoritmo. No te preocupes por si el bucle de `prime_number` se pueda acortar en su ejecución. En principio no puedes suponer nada y debes asumir que siempre se ejecuta completo como el peor caso posible. En cuanto a la expresión `int(N[::-1])` en realidad no tiene nada qué ver con la cantidad de elementos que haya en la entrada, así que su complejidad es `O(1)`. En global, la complejidad se queda en `O(N²)`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de tu explicacion super completa , :) me ha servido bastante n.n!!! muchisimas gracias de verdad

Comment: Y modificarias algo del algoritmo o crees que este bien implementado?

Comment: @ChemaCortes Gracias por tus comentarios. Respecto a lo de `int(N[::-1])`, me di cuenta de que esta `N` no es el tamaño del problema, pero creo que está relacionado, ya que cuanto mayor sea la lista inicial, mayores serán los primos que se van encontrando, y por tanto mayor será el número de dígitos de éstos, lo que influye en el tiempo para "darles la vuelta". Pero ahora me doy cuenta de que la complejidad de esa función sería más bien `log(N)`, pues el número de dígitos de N es función de su logaritmo.

Comment: @Eps11101 ¿El código es tuyo? Yo lo veo correcto, pero hay cosas que escribiría de otra forma más "pythonica", además de que se le podrían hacer algunas optimizaciones para reducir el tiempo de ejecución. Pero creo que eso es más bien material para otra pregunta, pues no cabe en un comentario ni creo que proceda aumentar esta respuesta.

Comment: @abulafia Incluso como `log(N)` sería despreciable frente a `O(N^2)`. En la evaluación del algoritmo no se tiene en consideración la representación de los números, si no también debería considerarse `str(i)` por los mismos motivos. Con `O(N^2)` no hay nada qué hacer. Sin embargo, acortando el bucle a `range(2, sqrt(N))` ya tendríamos un `O(N^1.5)`, comparable con el algoritmo de Karatsuba que python aplica al operar con enteros grandes (del orden de `O(log(N)^1.585)`).

Comment: @abulafia y para esta función, t(n): 4n*log(3n), O(n), o O(nlog(n))?

Comment: @FranciscoMinchalaFajardo No te entiendo. Quieres decir cuál es la complejidad de computar esa función, o bien que has computado la complejidad de un código y te ha salido eso? Si es lo segundo,esa complejidad sería `O(n*log(n))`. No puedes quedarte con `O(n)` porque se están multiplicando y no sumando. Sería como si dijeras entonces que O(n*n) es O(n).

Comment: @abulafia si exacto tenía esa función es la que he computado.  Entonces si tengo dos funciones por ejemplo: nlog(n) y 4nlog(3n) tendrían un similar orden O(nlog(n))? .... y para otro ejemplo; digamos dos funciones: 1^n y 245, tiene un similar orden O(1) verdad?  o no tienen no son comparables en relación al orden estas dos ?

Comment: Sí, `n log(n)` y `4n log(3n)` tienen la misma complejdidad, `O(n log(n))`. Sin embargo el segundo ejemplo no lo entiendo. ¿Cómo puede tener algo complejidad 1^? Eso es 1 sin que importe el valor de n. ¿En qué tipo de código o algoritmo puede aparecer una complejidad 1^n? Ahora bien, si quitamos la n, entonces si lo veo más claro. 1 y 245 ambas tienen complejidad O(1).